# TeamCity SMB deployer - failed to connect via SMB protocol

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, smb

I've tried to upload files from the server with installed TeamCity server and TeamCity Build Agent via SMB protocol to server with SMB network share folder, but I've gotten the error:

```
Step 3/3: Upload build to a Network Share (SMB Upload) (7s)
[04:11:21]  [Step 3/3] Starting upload via SMB to 
\someServerName\SomeShareFolder
[04:11:28]  [Step 3/3] jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 
someServerName/192.***.4.194
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.readn(Transport.java:29)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.peekKey(SmbTransport.java:388)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.negotiate(SmbTransport.java:288)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doConnect(SmbTransport.java:319)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:241)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.run(Transport.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[04:11:28]  [Step 3/3] Step Upload build to a Network Share (SMB Upload) failed
```

TeamCity server and Build Agent are installed on the same server. TeamCity is Professional 2017.1.4 (build 47070). Build Step settings:
[image]

I've checked SMB1 protocol on both servers. It's enabled.
The server with installed TeamCity Build Agent and TeamCity server(OS Windows 10):
[image]

The server with SMB share folder (OS Windows Server 2012 ):
[image]

In manual mode, all work ok. I successfully copy files from one server to another server into SMB share folder. What is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ooops.SMB protocol is disabled on the local network on the router level.