# SMB Upload on TeamCity build step failing due to connect timeout

Tags: teamcity, protocols, smb

Been using TeamCity (2018.2.2 (build 61245) to deploy a website via a Git repo. It has three build steps and it's suddenly failing on the second, the SMB Upload step:

> [07:33:02]Step 1/3: Clear folder (Command Line) (3s)
>
> [07:33:04][Step 1/3] Starting: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\agentTmp\custom_script4232052461125577569.cmd
>
> [07:33:04][Step 1/3] in directory: C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\f5f9b0bd3b4556c2
>
> [07:33:05][Step 1/3] Process exited with code 0
>
> [07:33:06]Step 2/3: SMB Upload (6s)
>
> [07:33:07][Step 2/3] Starting upload via SMB to \\SERVERNAME\folder_name
>
> [07:33:12][Step 2/3] Deployment problem: connect timed out
>
> [07:33:12][Step 2/3] Step SMB Upload failed

I can't get any more details that this and I'm tearing out my hair to try and fix it as we can't do anything until this works!

\\SERVERNAME\folder_name is a valid path and share, and SMB is enabled as a protocol on that share. We're using an Amazon AWS EC2 Windows Server 2008, and I checked SMBv1 is enabled.

The only change that was made was we enabled TLS1.2 (instead of the working 1.1 we had), and after reboot this stopped working.

Any ideas? The only similar question I found was [TeamCity SMB deployer - failed to connect via SMB protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928469/teamcity-smb-deployer-failed-to-connect-via-smb-protocol) and that has a rather unhelpful solution!

Comment: This is still outstanding. I've logged it with TeamCity and they have come back with some suggestions. See this link https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003170320-SMB-Upload-on-TeamCity-build-step-failing-due-to-connect-timeout. I have tried upgrading Java and that had no effect. If anything else does I'll come back and update this.